# How To Put Sections Side By Side?

Tags: html, css

I am making a blog website for myself. I want tags and let's talk section next to hot topics and latest news as a box but I couldn't do it for 1 day now. I don't want them above the footer and with that weight. I want them as a box next to hot topics and the latest news. I shared my codes on the code snippet. Thank you already. I am a newbie around so I hope I asked the question correctly.

I want something like that:

[image]

```css
.main {
  background: var(--background-secondary);
  padding: var(--py) 0;
}

.blog .h2 {
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog-card-group {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.blog-card {
  background: var(--background-primary);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.blog-card:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  background: hsl(225, 100%, 87%);
}

.blog-card-banner {
  display: none;
}

.blog-content-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.blog-topic {
  background: var(--action-secondary);
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 0.25rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blog-topic:hover {
  background: var(--foreground-secondary);
  color: var(--action-secondary);
}

.blog-card .h3 {
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blog-card .h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}

.blog-text,
.profile-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.blog .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
}

.blog .h4 {
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
}

.blog .h4:hover {
  color: var(--accent);
}

.blog .text-sm {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  color: var(--foreground-tertiary);
}

.blog .separator {
  background: var(--foreground-tertiary);
  margin-inline: 3px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.blog ion-icon {
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 50px;
}

.load-more {
  margin-inline: auto;
  background: var(--foreground-secondary);
  color: var(--background-secondary);
  padding: 0.6875rem 1.1875rem;
}

.load-more:hover {
  background: var(--accent);
}


/* ASIDE */

.aside {
  display: none;
}


/* BLOG */

.blog .h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.blog .h2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--action-primary);
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.blog-text,
.profile-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.blog-text {
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  font-size: var(--fs-4);
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blog .wrapper-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.profile-wrapper {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background: var(--action-primary);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile-wrapper img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blog .wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 0;
}


/* ASIDE */

.aside {
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.aside .h2 {
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.aside .wrapper {
  background: var(--background-primary);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
}

.topics {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.topic-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: var(--background-primary);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topic-btn:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.topic-btn .icon-box {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--action-primary);
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
}

.topic-btn:hover .icon-box {
  background: var(--accent);
  color: var(--white);
}

.topic-btn ion-icon {
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 40px;
}

.topic-btn p {
  padding: 15px;
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tags {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.tags .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2rem;
}

.tags .hashtag {
  background: var(--action-primary);
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: var(--fs-5);
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.contact {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.contact p {
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.social-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.social-links .icon-box {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: var(--action-secondary);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.newsletter {
  position: sticky;
  top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 98px;
}

.newsletter p {
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.newsletter input {
  border: none;
  background: var(--action-primary);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font: inherit;
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.newsletter input::placeholder {
  color: inherit;
}

.newsletter input:focus {
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

.newsletter .btn-primary {
  margin-inline: auto;
  margin: auto;
}


}
#TOPICS .topic-card {
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: var(--radius-8);
}
.topic-card .card-content {
  margin-block-end: 15px;
}
.topic-card .card-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: var(--fontSize-6);
  margin-block: 15px 20px;
}
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
.btn-icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-radius: var(--radius-circle);
  color: var(--white);
}
.btn-icon:is(:hover, :focus-visible) {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 42%)
}
.slider {
  --slider-items: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 16%;
}
.slider-list {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  transition: transform var(--transition-2);
}
.slider-item {
  min-width: 100%;
}
.slider-card {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.slider-card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-image: var(--gradient-3);
  border-radius: var(--radius-8);
}
.slider-list .slider-banner {
  border-radius: var(--radius-8);
  border: 10px solid white;
}
.slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
.slider-title {
  color: var(--text-columbia-blue);
  font-weight: var(--weight-bold);
  margin-block-end: 5px;
  transition: var(--transition-1);
}
.slider-card:is(:hover, :focus-visible) .slider-title {
  color: var(--text-carolina-blue);
}
.slider-subtitle {
  font-size: var(--fontSize-7);
}

/**
 * TOPICS
 */
.topics .section-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.slider {
  --slider-items: 3;
}

/**
 * TOPICS
 */
.topic-card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}
section#topics {
  background-color: hsl(235, 86%, 65%);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
section#topics:hover {
  background-color: hsl(225, 59%, 65%);
}
.slider-content {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.slider-title {
  font-size: var(--fontSize-5);
}
.slider-subtitle {
  font-size: var(--fontSize-6);
}
.btn-icon {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <article>
      <section class="topics" id="topics" aria-labelledby="topic-label">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="card topic-card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h2 class="headline headline-2 section-title card-title" id="topic-label">
                Hot Topics
              </h2>

              <p class="card-text">
                Don't miss out on the latest news about Travel tips, Hotels review, Food guide...
              </p>

              <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn-icon" aria-label="previous" data-slider-prev>
                  <ion-icon name="arrow-back" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
                </button>

                <button class="btn-icon" aria-label="next" data-slider-next>
                  <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider" data-slider>
              <ul class="slider-list" data-slider-container>
                <li class="slider-item">
                  <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                    <figure class="slider-banner img-holder" style="--width: 307; --height: 318">
                      <img src="./images/dev.jpeg" width="307" height="318" loading="lazy" alt="Sport" class="img-cover" />
                    </figure>

                    <div class="slider-content">
                      <span class="slider-title">Sport</span>

                      <p class="slider-subtitle">38 Articles</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="slider-item">
                  <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                    <figure class="slider-banner img-holder" style="--width: 307; --height: 318">
                      <img src="./images/dev1.png" width="307" height="318" loading="lazy" alt="Travel" class="img-cover" />
                    </figure>

                    <div class="slider-content">
                      <span class="slider-title">Travel</span>

                      <p class="slider-subtitle">63 Articles</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="slider-item">
                  <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                    <figure class="slider-banner img-holder" style="--width: 307; --height: 318">
                      <img src="./images/dev2.jpeg" width="307" height="318" loading="lazy" alt="Design" class="img-cover" />
                    </figure>

                    <div class="slider-content">
                      <span class="slider-title">Design</span>

                      <p class="slider-subtitle">78 Articles</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="slider-item">
                  <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                    <figure class="slider-banner img-holder" style="--width: 307; --height: 318">
                      <img src="./images/developer.webp" width="307" height="318" loading="lazy" alt="Movie" class="img-cover" />
                    </figure>

                    <div class="slider-content">
                      <span class="slider-title">Movie</span>

                      <p class="slider-subtitle">125 Articles</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>

                <li class="slider-item">
                  <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                    <figure class="slider-banner img-holder" style="--width: 307; --height: 318">
                      <img src="./images/developer1.jpeg" width="307" height="318" loading="lazy" alt="Lifestyle" class="img-cover" />
                    </figure>

                    <div class="slider-content">
                      <span class="slider-title">Lifestyle</span>

                      <p class="slider-subtitle">78 Articles</p>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>



      <!-- BLOG SECTION -->
      <div class="blog">
        <h2 class="h2"> Latest Blog Post</h2>
        <div class="blog-card-group">
          <div class="blog-card">
            <div class="blog-card-banner">
              <img src="./images/blog-1.png" alt="MongoDB" width="250" class="blog-banner-img">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
              <button class="blog-topc text-tiny">
                                    Database
                                </button>
              <h3>
                <a href="#" class="h3">
                                        Building microservices with Dropwizard, MongoDB & Docker
                                    </a>
              </h3>
              <p class="blog-text">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit
              </p>
              <div class="wrapper-flex">
                <div class="profile-wrapper">
                  <img src="./images/profile (1).jpg" alt="Buse Nur Çetin">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <a href="#" class="h4"> Buse Nur Çetin </a>
                  <p class="text-sm">
                    <time datetime="2023.04.23"> April,23,2023</time>
                    <span class="seperator"> </span>
                    <ion-icon name="time-outline"></ion-icon>
                    <time datetime="PT3M"> 3 Min </time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-card">
            <div class="blog-card-banner">
              <img src="./images/blog-5.png" alt="MongoDB" width="250" class="blog-banner-img">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
              <button class="blog-topc text-tiny">Database</button>
              <h3>
                <a href="#" class="h3">Building microservices with Dropwizard, MongoDB & Docker</a>
              </h3>
              <p class="blog-text">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              </p>
              <div class="wrapper-flex">
                <div class="profile-wrapper">
                  <img src="./images/profile (1).jpg" alt="Buse Nur Çetin">
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <a href="#" class="h4"> Buse Nur Çetin </a>
                  <p class="text-sm">
                    <time datetime="2023.04.23"> April,23,2023</time>
                    <span class="seperator"> </span>
                    <ion-icon name="time-outline"></ion-icon>
                    <time datetime="PT3M"> 3 Min </time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn load-more">
                        Load More...
                    </button>
        </div>
        <!-- ASIDE -->

        <div class="aside">
          <div class="topics">
            <h2 class="h2">
              <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <ion-icon name="server-outline"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <p>Database</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <ion-icon name="accessibility-outline"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <p>Accessibility</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <ion-icon name="rocket-outline"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <p>Web Performance</p>
              </a>

            </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="tags">
            <h2 class="h2">
              Tags
            </h2>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <button class="hashtag">#html</button>
              <button class="hashtag">#css</button>
              <button class="hashtag">#bootstrap</button>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="contact">
            <h2 class="h2">Let's Talk</h2>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <p>
                Do you want to learn more about how can I help your company overcome problems? Let us have a conversation.
              </p>
              <ul class="social-links">
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="icon-box discord">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="icon-box twitter">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="icon-box medium">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-medium"></ion-icon>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="" class="icon-box linkedin">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="newsletter">
            <h2 class="h2">
              Newsletter
            </h2>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, consequuntur!
              </p>
              <form action="#">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Subscribe </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </main>
```

Comment: Can you share some examples, So we can understand what your trying to achieve?

Comment: I added an image in question thanks for your advice @mr.Hritik

Comment: Note that your markup is invalid as you have more reopening tags then closing tags. Some elements have been closed before others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to separate the divs to achieve your desired output, So I separate the divs into `<article>` & `<aside>`.
2. After separating the divs you can use `Flexbox` or `GRID`. I applied the `display: flex` property on the parent div it will bring them side by side.
3. Also, you can adjust their width with the `flex` property.
4. For your reference I'm sharing the link to an article which shows how to use Flexbox & Grid [CSS Grid Vs. Flexbox:](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/css-tutorial/css-grid-vs-flexbox#:%7E:text=Grid%20utilizes%20a%20two%2Ddimensional,placed%20in%20a%20linear%20order.)

```css
.main{
  background: var(--background-secondary);
  padding: var(--py) 0;
    display: flex;
}
aside{
 flex:1;
}

article{
  flex:2;
}

.blog .h2{
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog-card-group{
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.blog-card{
  background: var(--background-primary);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.blog-card:hover{
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  background: hsl(225, 100%, 87%);
}

.blog-card-banner{
  display: none;
}

.blog-content-wrapper{
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.blog-topic{
  background: var(--action-secondary);
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 0.25rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blog-topic:hover{
  background: var(--foreground-secondary);
  color: var(--action-secondary);
}

.blog-card .h3{
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.blog-card .h3:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness:  2px;
}

.blog-text, .profile-wrapper{
  display: none;
}

.blog .wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
}

.blog .h4{
  color: var(--foreground-secondary);
}

.blog .h4:hover{
  color: var(--accent);
}

.blog .text-sm{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  color: var(--foreground-tertiary);
}

.blog .separator{
  background: var(--foreground-tertiary);
  margin-inline: 3px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.blog ion-icon{
  --ionicon-stroke-width: 50px;
}

.load-more{
  margin-inline: auto;
  background: var(--foreground-secondary);
  color: var(--background-secondary);
  padding: 0.6875rem 1.1875rem;
}

.load-more:hover{
  background: var(--accent);
}

/* ASIDE */





  /* BLOG */

  .blog .h2{
      position: relative;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 2rem;
  }

  .blog .h2::before{
      content:'' ;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: var(--action-primary);
      width: 5px;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .blog-text, .profile-wrapper{
      display: block;
  }

  .blog-text{
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      font-size: var(--fs-4);
      display: -webkit-box;
      line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .blog .wrapper-flex{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: start;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
  }

  .profile-wrapper{
      width: 56px;
      height: 56px;
      background: var(--action-primary);
      padding: 3px;
      border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .profile-wrapper img{
      border-radius:50% ;
  }

  .blog .wrapper{
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: start;
      gap: 0;
  }

  /* ASIDE */

  .aside{
     display: block;
     align-self: stretch;
  }

  .aside .h2{
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.3;
  }

  .aside .wrapper{
      background: var(--background-primary);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 40px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
  }

  .topics{
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .topic-btn{
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
      background: var(--background-primary);
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.05);
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .topic-btn:not(:last-child){
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .topic-btn .icon-box{
      font-size: 22px;
      width: 70px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: var(--action-primary);
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
  }

  .topic-btn:hover .icon-box{
      background: var(--accent);
      color: var(--white);
  }

  .topic-btn ion-icon{
      --ionicon-stroke-width:40px;
  }

  .topic-btn p{
      padding: 15px;
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      font-weight: 700;
  }

  .tags{
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .tags .wrapper{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap :0.2rem;
  }

  .tags .hashtag{
      background: var(--action-primary);
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      padding: 5px 10px;
      font-size: var(--fs-5);
      font-weight: 700;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }

   .contact{
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .contact p{
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .social-links{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
  }

  .social-links .icon-box{
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;
      background: var(--action-secondary);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 22px;
  }

  .newsletter{
      position: sticky;
      top: 3rem;
      margin-bottom: 98px;
  }

  .newsletter p{
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .newsletter input{
      border: none;
      background: var(--action-primary);
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      font: inherit;
      color: var(--foreground-secondary);
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  .newsletter input::placeholder{
      color: inherit;
  }

  .newsletter input:focus{
      outline: 2px solid;
      outline-offset: 0;
  }

  .newsletter .btn-primary{
      margin-inline: auto;
      margin: auto;
  }

}

#TOPICS

.topic-card {
padding: 24px;
border-radius: var(--radius-8);
}

.topic-card .card-content { margin-block-end: 15px; }

.topic-card .card-text {
color: white;
font-size: var(--fontSize-6);
margin-block: 15px 20px;
}

.btn-group {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
gap: 10px;
}

.btn-icon {
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
display: grid;
place-items: center;
background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
border-radius: var(--radius-circle);
color: var(--white);
}

.btn-icon:is(:hover, :focus-visible) { background: hsl(0, 0%, 42%)}

.slider {
--slider-items: 1;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 16%;
}

.slider-list {
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
gap: 20px;
transition: transform var(--transition-2);
}

.slider-item { min-width: 100%; }

.slider-card { position: relative; border-radius: 100%; }

.slider-card::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
background-image: var(--gradient-3);
border-radius: var(--radius-8);
}

.slider-list .slider-banner { border-radius: var(--radius-8); border: 10px solid white;}

.slider-content {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
left: 15px;
}

.slider-title {
color: var(--text-columbia-blue);
font-weight: var(--weight-bold);
margin-block-end: 5px;
transition: var(--transition-1);
}

.slider-card:is(:hover, :focus-visible) .slider-title { color: var(--text-carolina-blue); }

.slider-subtitle { font-size: var(--fontSize-7); }



/**
 * TOPICS
 */

.topics .section-title { font-size: 2rem; }
.slider { --slider-items: 3; }
/**
 * TOPICS
 */

.topic-card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

section#topics{
  background-color: hsl(235, 86%, 65%);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

section#topics:hover{
  background-color: hsl(225, 59%, 65%);
}


 
.slider-content {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.slider-title {
  font-size: var(--fontSize-5);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                      <article>
                        <section class="topics" id="topics" aria-labelledby="topic-label">
                          <div class="container">
                            <div class="card topic-card">
                              <div class="card-content">
                                <h2
                                  class="headline headline-2 section-title card-title"
                                  id="topic-label"
                                >
                                  Hot Topics
                                </h2>
                
                                <p class="card-text">
                                  Don't miss out on the latest news about Travel tips, Hotels
                                  review, Food guide...
                                </p>
                
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button
                                    class="btn-icon"
                                    aria-label="previous"
                                    data-slider-prev
                                  >
                                    <ion-icon name="arrow-back" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
                                  </button>
                
                                  <button class="btn-icon" aria-label="next" data-slider-next>
                                    <ion-icon
                                      name="arrow-forward"
                                      aria-hidden="true"
                                    ></ion-icon>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                
                              <div class="slider" data-slider>
                                <ul class="slider-list" data-slider-container>
                                  <li class="slider-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                                      <figure
                                        class="slider-banner img-holder"
                                        style="--width: 307; --height: 318"
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          src="./images/dev.jpeg"
                                          width="307"
                                          height="318"
                                          loading="lazy"
                                          alt="Sport"
                                          class="img-cover"
                                        />
                                      </figure>
                
                                      <div class="slider-content">
                                        <span class="slider-title">Sport</span>
                
                                        <p class="slider-subtitle">38 Articles</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </li>
                
                                  <li class="slider-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                                      <figure
                                        class="slider-banner img-holder"
                                        style="--width: 307; --height: 318"
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          src="./images/dev1.png"
                                          width="307"
                                          height="318"
                                          loading="lazy"
                                          alt="Travel"
                                          class="img-cover"
                                        />
                                      </figure>
                
                                      <div class="slider-content">
                                        <span class="slider-title">Travel</span>
                
                                        <p class="slider-subtitle">63 Articles</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </li>
                
                                  <li class="slider-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                                      <figure
                                        class="slider-banner img-holder"
                                        style="--width: 307; --height: 318"
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          src="./images/dev2.jpeg"
                                          width="307"
                                          height="318"
                                          loading="lazy"
                                          alt="Design"
                                          class="img-cover"
                                        />
                                      </figure>
                
                                      <div class="slider-content">
                                        <span class="slider-title">Design</span>
                
                                        <p class="slider-subtitle">78 Articles</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </li>
                
                                  <li class="slider-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                                      <figure
                                        class="slider-banner img-holder"
                                        style="--width: 307; --height: 318"
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          src="./images/developer.webp"
                                          width="307"
                                          height="318"
                                          loading="lazy"
                                          alt="Movie"
                                          class="img-cover"
                                        />
                                      </figure>
                
                                      <div class="slider-content">
                                        <span class="slider-title">Movie</span>
                
                                        <p class="slider-subtitle">125 Articles</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </li>
                
                                  <li class="slider-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="slider-card">
                                      <figure
                                        class="slider-banner img-holder"
                                        style="--width: 307; --height: 318"
                                      >
                                        <img
                                          src="./images/developer1.jpeg"
                                          width="307"
                                          height="318"
                                          loading="lazy"
                                          alt="Lifestyle"
                                          class="img-cover"
                                        />
                                      </figure>
                
                                      <div class="slider-content">
                                        <span class="slider-title">Lifestyle</span>
                
                                        <p class="slider-subtitle">78 Articles</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </section>



                <!-- BLOG SECTION -->
                <div class="blog">
                    <h2 class="h2"> Latest Blog Post</h2>
                    <div class="blog-card-group">
                        <div class="blog-card">
                            <div class="blog-card-banner">
                                <img src="./images/blog-1.png" alt="MongoDB" width="250" class="blog-banner-img">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
                                <button class="blog-topc text-tiny">
                                    Database
                                </button>
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="#" class="h3">
                                        Building microservices with Dropwizard, MongoDB & Docker
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <p class="blog-text">
                                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit 
                                </p>
                                <div class="wrapper-flex">
                                    <div class="profile-wrapper">
                                        <img src="./images/profile (1).jpg" alt="Buse Nur Çetin">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" class="h4"> Buse Nur Çetin </a>
                                        <p class="text-sm">
                                            <time datetime="2023.04.23"> April,23,2023</time>
                                            <span class="seperator"> </span>
                                                <ion-icon name="time-outline"></ion-icon>
                                          <time datetime="PT3M"> 3 Min </time>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog-card">
                            <div class="blog-card-banner">
                                <img src="./images/blog-5.png" alt="MongoDB" width="250" class="blog-banner-img">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
                                <button class="blog-topc text-tiny">
                                    Database
                                </button>
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="#" class="h3">
                                        Building microservices with Dropwizard, MongoDB & Docker
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <p class="blog-text">
                                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                                </p>
                                <div class="wrapper-flex">
                                    <div class="profile-wrapper">
                                        <img src="./images/profile (1).jpg" alt="Buse Nur Çetin">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wrapper">
                                        <a href="#" class="h4"> Buse Nur Çetin </a>
                                        <p class="text-sm">
                                            <time datetime="2023.04.23"> April,23,2023</time>
                                            <span class="seperator"> </span>
                                                <ion-icon name="time-outline"></ion-icon>
                                                <time datetime="PT3M"> 3 Min </time>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <button class="btn load-more">
                        Load More...
                    </button>
                </div>
                      </div>
        </div>
              </article>
                <!-- ASIDE -->
                            <aside>
                <div class="aside">
                    <div class="topics">
                        <h2 class="h2">
                            <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                                <div class="icon-box">
                                    <ion-icon name="server-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </div>
                                <p>Database</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                                <div class="icon-box">
                                    <ion-icon name="accessibility-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </div>
                                <p>Accessibility</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="topic-btn">
                                <div class="icon-box">
                                    <ion-icon name="rocket-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </div>
                                <p>Web Performance</p>
                            </a>

                        </h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tags">
                        <h2 class="h2">
                            Tags
                        </h2>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <button class="hashtag">#html</button>
                            <button class="hashtag">#css</button>
                            <button class="hashtag">#bootstrap</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="contact">
                        <h2 class="h2">Let's Talk</h2>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <p>
                                Do you want to learn more about how can I help your company overcome problems?
                                Let us have a conversation.
                            </p>
                            <ul class="social-links">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="" class="icon-box discord">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="" class="icon-box twitter">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="" class="icon-box medium">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-medium"></ion-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="" class="icon-box linkedin">
                                        <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="newsletter">
                        <h2 class="h2">
                            Newsletter
                        </h2>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, consequuntur!
                            </p>
                            <form action="#">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Subscribe </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> 
  </aside>
    </main>
```

Comment: hello thank you your answer helped a lot. I have one more question. How can I give 2 block for hot topics and latest blog post and 1 block for tag and lets talk?

Comment: @BuseNurÇetin You want 2 blocks for hot topics and the latest blog post, So you can add image and text right?

Comment: Because if you want some help with  hot topics and the latest blog post,, You can refer this codepens 'https://codepen.io/HenrikFricke/pen/GRNYrXK' & 'https://codepen.io/JavaScriptJunkie/pen/WgRBxw '.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to do this would be to put `display: inline-block;` onto the CSS of the `<div>` elements which you want next to eachother.

You can check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display to see what other display options you have, and which ones might suit your needs more.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work either